# Newline character(\n) in scanf

Tags: c, printf, newline, scanf

Suppose i write the code below:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    scanf("%d\n",&a);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

The input is taken and the cursor is blinking in the next line without printing the value of `a`.
But if I remove the `\n` character, it is printing the value of `a` automatically in the next line.
Even if I place a `\n`, before the `%d` in `scanf` (`scanf("%d\n",&a);`), it is not moving the cursor to the next line, and taking the input, instead of being taking input in the next line. So, does `scanf` automatically takes input in next lines? and does `\n` cannot be used with the `scanf` function??

Actually, my problem wants me to input three integers in three line. It is written `Input:
Three integers on three lines.`
But on trying to use `\n` in `scanf`, it is only showing a cursor blinking in the next line after taking the input.

Answer (score 1):

Any whitespace-character (as determined by [`isspace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace)) in the format-string for [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) will cause it to read and discard characters until the next character read would be non-whitespace, or an error occurs.

You didn't enter any other non-whitespace than the number? Well, have fun waiting.

Comment: Thanks for ur help,but i am not getting it,can u please explain in a simple way.I just inputted a number and pressed enter but it is not printing the number i have inputted.

Comment: @MathsManiac: Of course it is still waiting.  It will continue to wait until you type something that isn't a white space after the number.  You could type a letter or a digit or a punctuation character — but typing blanks, tabs or newlines will just leave `scanf()` looking for something else.  Remove the trailing newline from the input format — such trailing white space is unconditionally a disaster for interactive I/O and seldom if ever wise for non-interactive I/O.  If you want to read lines of input, do so — using `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` — and then parse what was read.