# Need help about inputting strings and printing it out

Tags: c

I am stuck on a part of an assignment I am writing.

When I am typing in the postalCode (which is `A8A 4J4`) it shows

[image: output1]

[image: output2]

It is supposed to be:

```
Postal code: A8A 4J4
City: Toronto
```

It is skipping the option to enter the City.

I've tried `%[^\n]` and it still skips the option to enter the City.

My current code is:

```
if (option == 'y' || option == 'Y') {
    printf("Please enter the contact's apartment number: ");
    scanf("%u", &address.apartmentNumber);

    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf("%s", &address.postalCode);
}

if (option == 'n' || option == 'N') {
    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf("%s", &address.postalCode);
}

printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
scanf("%40s", address.city);

printf("Postal code: %s\n", address.postalCode);
printf("City: %s\n", address.city);
```

I saw a post about this already but the answers there didn't help. I already tried the [^\n] in my `scanf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197006/the-scanf-function-the-specifer-s-and-the-new-line  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905009/reading-newline-from-previous-input-when-reading-from-keyboard-with-scanf

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45394221/newline-character-n-in-scanf or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740024/scanf-asking-twice-for-input-while-i-expect-it-to-ask-only-once

Comment: You could try `scanf("%s ", &address.postalCode);` to eat the trailing whitespace or `scanf(" %40s", address.city);` to eat the leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

The better for string input is `fgets` as `scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", &address.city)`; does not work well if the the line is only `"\n"` or too long. Stick with `fgets()`.

```
 fgets(address.city,40,stdin);
```

EDIT: If you still want to use `scanf` use like this

```
 scanf (" %[^\n]%*c", &address.city)
```

it will scan characters until it finds `'\n'`

Answer (score 0):

Put the `&` on your reference to `address.city`
like this

```
scanf("%40s", &address.city);
```

Comment: Or use this scanf("%s", &address.city); You need the ampersand.

Comment: I've tried everything and found that `scanf(" %[^\n]", &address.postalCode); `and `scanf(" %40s", address.city);` worked. Thanks for the help.